# (NODEJS) array is empty after looping in asynchronous

Tags: node.js, promise

```
_processInstructionItems(employerId, programs)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let self = this;
        let listOfPrograms = [];
        _.forEach(programs, item => {
            Program.find(item.id).then(programData => {
                this._processProgramItemCode(employerId, item, programData).then(programItem => {
                    listOfPrograms.push(programItem)
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
        resolve(listOfPrograms)
    })
}
```

Sample Payload

```
return {
    user_id: 'ADMIN_TEST',
    employer_id: '202693450004',
    programs: [
      {
        id: 1,
        period: [
          {
            date: '2016-07-01'
          },
          {
            date: '2016-08-01'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        period: [
          {
            date: '2016-09-01'
          },
          {
            date: '2016-10-01'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm wondering why the array is still empty after pushing the resolve data inside the promise.

NOTE: I'm kinda still new in this language so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code in the question

Comment: @AmiramKorach done

Comment: You don't need to store the `this` anymore since you're using arrow functions. It will use the `this` of `_processInstructionItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bacause find is async and you immediately resolved the empty array.
The correct code should be something like:

```js
_processInstructionItems(employerId, programs)
    {
      let self = this;
      let listOfPrograms = [];
      return Program.find({_id: {$in: _.map(programs, 'id')}})
      .then(programsData =>
            {
        let promises = programsData.map(p => this._processProgramItemCode(employerId, p);
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this once I got home.

Comment: Please include how the user is supposed to use the function and get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with using promises, but it very much looks like you expect your `listOfPrograms` to contain something you add to it via asynchronous calls; as soon as something is async, your code will "fall through" immediately to the `resolve()` function call, but your array will still be empty.

It's difficult to tell whether your functions in the middle of this thing are actually synchronous or asynchronous, but if any of the functions you call are, the behavior you describe would be expected.

A couple of weeks ago I wrote up some things that piqued me (coming from desktop development in C++/C#) with node.js, perhaps that might help you as well: http://dev.haufe.com/node-js-primer-for-old-school-developers/

Especially the bit with the async for loop looks very similar to what you are describing here.

Comment: All of the functions that is included in the snippet contains promise. 

I thought I was doing fine until this issue pops up.